# Lami's Theorem Problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium

Lami's Theorem states that the magnitude of each force in an equilibrium  state consisting of three coplanar, concurrent forces acting at a point is directly proportional to the sine of the angle between the remaining forces in equilibrium.

Let $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$ be the three forces and $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ be the angles between the forces $(F_2,F_3)$, $(F_1,F_3)$ and $(F_1,F_2)$ respectively
$$F_1\propto \sin \alpha$$
$$F_2\propto \sin \beta$$
$$F_3\propto \sin \gamma$$

Say $F_1=F_2=F_3= 10 N$ and if the angle between the two forces $F_2$ and $F_3$ is equal to $0$, i.e., $(\alpha=0)$ then $F_1$ must be zero right? Since $\sin \alpha$ is directly proportional to $F_1$, and if that's the case the system can't be in equilibrium since the two other forces acting on the point exert a net force of 20N.

Can anyone help me find the discrepancy in my understanding?

Comment: I don't know if it's satisfactory answer or not but as far as I know lamis theorem only hold for forces which forms a closed traingle in vector diagram in your case it's not forming a closed traingle so we can't apply it and also in your case object can never be in equilibrium as F2 and f3 are in same direction so even if F1 is opposite to both net force will be 10 N as u have given F1=10

Comment: As you yourself mentioned that it won't be in equilibrium that means you can't apply Lami's theorem . So no such sin(alpha) to worry about !

Comment: If an angle between two of the forces is $0$ and the remaining force is non-zero, then the proportionality factor in Lami's theorem is infinite. You can then derive that the other two angles also must have sine zero.